# Difference between For and $.each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I use `.each()` both console logs return the same value, but if I use `for` the second one returns only the array length, length of the array times. What's the difference between them? What am I missing?

```js
    //for (var i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) 
    $.each(streamers, function(i,data) {
        console.log(i);
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + data + '?callback=?', function(data) {
            console.log(i);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This code doesn't even look valid..

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev What's wrong with that code snippet?

Comment: @Vohuman He was missing a lot of closing brackets but it was just edited. Disregard ;)

Comment: I think the `streamers` should be inside quote

Comment: `getJSON` is asynchronusly does mean the request is running in the background, and calls your function back when it got a response then execute the `console.log(i)`. and that will happen in the both `foreach` and `for`.

Comment: Could you post the two code samples you are comparing separately?

Answer (score 0):

With `$.each` you are creating a closure for each iteration in which `i` is not changed.

With a `for` loop, `i` is changed before the `$.getJSON` callback is executed, so it will show the last possible value (because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous).

Comment: Even if the the `GET` requests were instantaneous, `i` would still change before the callbacks.  The *current code* has to finish running before the "async" code can run.

Comment: @just.another.programmer If it was instantaneous, it wouldn't be asynchronous.

Comment: Yes and no.  There would be no reason to, but if you wanted to, you could still execute it async.  Async just means that the code does not run in order with where it is written.  It runs at some unspecified "later time" when the thread is available.

Comment: @just.another.programmer Interesting, so you could use `setTimeout` with `0` delay, and it would still run at the end of the code. Useful!

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You don't even need to pass the `0`, just use `setTimeout(yourCode)` and it will eval after the entire current call finishes.